# Can't use class because come components are package private

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I created a Firebase class so I wouldn't have to constantly write out everything, but when I try to reorganize my app into packages that represent the different parts of the app, I get the following problems. I would like to keep the convenience of having a unique class for Firebase. Does anyone know how I can get around this? I'm new to coding so I apologize if this is something obvious.

[image]

[image]

```
public class firebaseUtility {

    public FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public DatabaseReference userDatabaseRef;
    public DatabaseReference databaseRef;
    public StorageReference storageRef;
    Map userInfo;

    //GETS USER ID

    String getUserIdString (){
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    }

    //GET GENERAL DATABASE REFERENCE

    DatabaseReference getDatabaseRef (){
        databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        return databaseRef;
    }

    //GETS USER DATABASE REFERENCE

    DatabaseReference getUserDatabaseRef (String uId){
        userDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uId);
        return userDatabaseRef;
    }
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show images of code.  You should copy the code into the question and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Also, if you omit the visibility modifier of a method, that method becomes *package private*, meaning that classes in the same package can access the method, but classes outside the package cannot. Refer to the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @BartBarnard Thank you for the link. I had thought that the public was applied in all instances if left blank but apparently not! Fixed and working. Just had to add public next to the methods. Cheers.